# PHP imagick, remove profiles and transform color space to RGB

Tags: php, imagick

The following script uploads image files, resizes to defined max width, compresses and saves a thumbnail image to a different location.
This works great so far but I'm strugglin with a few issues:

stripImage() should remove the color profile, but when I check the uploaded files, they still include the profile.(?)

transformImageColorspace should transform the colorspace to RGB. But when I upload a grey scale image, it does not transform to RGB.

Any ideas on how to fix these issues?
(PHP Version 8.1/Imagick 3.7)

```
<?PHP
  $maxWidth = 3000;
  $path = "../files/";
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
    $img = new imagick();
    $thumbsPath = str_replace('files', 'thumbs', $path);
    $img->readImage($path);
    $img->transformImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);// does not work
    if ($img->getImageWidth() > $maxWidth) $img->resizeImage($maxWidth, null, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0.9);
    if ($img->getImageFormat() == 'jpg' || 'jpeg') {
      $img->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
      $img->setImageCompressionQuality(82);
    }
    $img->stripImage();// does not work
    $img->writeImage($path);
    $img->thumbnailImage(300, null);
    $img->writeImage($thumbsPath);
    $img->destroy();
  }
?>
```

Comment: Update: just realized that an image with the color space set to CMYK is getting transformed to SRGB correctly. So the question narrows down to on how to tranform a greyscale image to SRGB.
The stripImage removes all metadata. Somehow a standard (sRGB)-profile is attached afterwards. But that is not a big deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `$img->setType(Imagick::IMGTYPE_TRUECOLOR);` directly after reading the image solved the issue.